# When using Powershell Get-Content, how do you replace a string with a backslash

Tags: powershell

In powershell if you have a string such as

> Server\MyName

how to you replace it with

> MyOtherServer\AnotherName

I have tried escaping with ' and using single quotes but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `-replace` operator, but it takes a regular expression (so you have to escape backslashes):

```
$s -replace 'Server\\MyName', 'MyOtherServer\AnotherName'
```

Of course, the necessary escaping only applies to the regex, not the replacement.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise the first argument was a regex which was the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Replace method, it doesn't require you to escape slashes:

```
$s.Replace('Server\MyName','MyOtherServer\AnotherName')
```